# Download terraform plan as a file from GitHub

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

I am working on a GitHub Actions pipeline where I am creating a terraform plan and then after downloading and reviewing the plan in a file authentication the apply stage. Everything is working smoothly, I get a plan that I am then saving as a tt file using the `'out'` flag, but I am not able to figure out how to download the plan file from the runner to my local machine or even save it as an artifact. Please help me out if there is a workaround.

```
name: 'Terraform PR'
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: infrastructure/env/dev-slb-alpha/dev
    permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: write

    steps:
      - name: Clone Repository (Latest)
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        if: github.event.inputs.git-ref != ''
      - name: Clone Repository (Custom Ref)
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        if: github.event.inputs.git-ref == ''
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.event.inputs.git-ref }}

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@master
        with:
          role-to-assume: arn:aws:iam::262267462662:role/slb-dev-github-actions
          aws-region: us-east-1
          # role-session-name: GithubActionsSession
      - name: Setup Terraform
        uses: hashicorp/setup-terraform@v1
        with:
          terraform_version: 1.1.2

      - name: Terraform Format
        id: fmt
        run: terraform fmt -check

      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: |
          # cd infrastructure/env/dev-slb-alpha/dev
          terraform init
      - name: Terraform Validate
        id: validate
        run: terraform validate -no-color

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        continue-on-error: true
        run: |
          # cd infrastructure/env/dev-slb-alpha/dev
          touch tfplan.txt
          # terraform force-unlock -force d5f2d86a-e0f6-222f-db3f-2c1d792ed528
          # terraform force-unlock -force QOCDA86JVO02CCFV3SB010RGP3VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG
          terraform plan -lock=false -input=false -out=tfplan.txt
          readlink -f tfplan.txt


      - name: terraform plan upload
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
         name: plan
         path: tfplan.txt
         retention-days: 5
         
      - uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
         name: my-plan
         path: tfplan.txt
       

      - name: Terraform Apply
        id: apply
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: |
          cd infrastructure/env/dev-slb-alpha/dev
          terraform force-unlock -force 8de3f689-282e-12fd-72b2-cdd27f94e4da
          terraform apply
```

Comment: Artifacts uploaded with that `actions/upload-artifact` action should appear on the page describing your run in the GitHub Actions web UI, as long as you have sufficient access in the repository. If you have access then you can follow a link to download a zip file containing the uploaded files.

Comment: However, downloading a plan file for local use might not be as useful as you think. Terraform typically expects a plan to be applied on the same computer where it was created, and so unless your local system is similar enough to the GitHub Actions execution environment Terraform on your local system will probably refuse to interact with that plan file created remotely.

Comment: I will be doing a terraform apply from the GH runner itself, but my plan turns out to be 4k worth of lines of code which is a bit much for GH and I am getting the argument list too long error, so to verify the changes on GitHub I will have to download the file first check for the changes and then approve the apply step.

Comment: So basically what I am trying to do is create the plan and save it on the runner itself and then download it from the runner. If there is any other way except for going the artifacts route, I would be fine with that too.